# Unable to use images outside of images/logos/base for my Nagios map due to permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, nagios

I am using `hostextinfo` statements in order to display icons in my map. For example:

```
define hostextinfo {
    hostgroup_name  apple-devices
    icon_image      base/apple.png
    icon_image_alt  Apple
    vrml_image      apple.png
    statusmap_image base/apple.gd2
}
```

This is working nicely.

However, when I am using the following statement in order to use images that are stored in  `htdocs/images/logos/symbols` rather than `htdocs/images/logos/base`, it is not working and an interrogation point is displayed in place of the expected logo.

```
define hostextinfo{
    hostgroup_name  network-devices
    icon_image      symbols/switch.png
    icon_image_alt  Switch
    vrml_image      switch.png
    statusmap_image symbols/switch.gd2
}
```

So far, here is what I have tried:

- I have made sure to verify that the files exists and that they have the proper permissions.
- I also tried to display the images directly by using the addresses in the browser. I have noticed that `http://obfuscated.net/nagios3/images/logos/base/` is returning `403 Forbidden` but `http://obfuscated.net/nagios3/images/logos/symbols/` is returning `404 Not Found`.
- I have looked into the `apache2.conf` and `cgi.cfg` files to figure out the images permissions without success.

*EDIT* Here are some listings to show the file permissions. I am unable to see what is different between `base` and `symbols`

```
/usr/share/nagios/htdocs/images/logos# ls -l .
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Nov 25 08:38 andrade
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 base
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 bernhard
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Nov 25 08:38 cook
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 didier
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Nov 25 08:38 logos
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 remus
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 satrapa
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 symbols
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 08:38 werschler

/usr/share/nagios/htdocs/images/logos# ls -l base/switch40.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 869 Dec  6  2009 base/switch40.png

/usr/share/nagios/htdocs/images/logos# ls -l symbols/router.png 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 169 Dec  6  2009 symbols/router.png
```

Do you know where the permissions for apache2 to access those images are stored?

Comment: _However, when I am using the following statement in order to use images that are stored in_ **`htdocs/images/logos/base`** _rather than `htdocs/images/logos/base`_ --> Do you mean `htdocs/images/logos/symbols`? If so, please show us the permission of this folder and the image files inside?

Comment: But wait, I'm confusing about your title: _Unable to use images_ **outside of logos/images**.

Comment: @quanta Thank you for paying attention to my question. I fixed a bunch of typos and added the information you requested.

Comment: Do you use selinux? Then also post `ls -Z`

Comment: @Peter No. I am not using selinux.

Comment: What did you see in the Apache error log when requesting `http://obfuscated.net/nagios3/images/logos/symbols/` or `http://obfuscated.net/nagios3/images/logos/symbols/router.png`? Have you tried to rename `symbols` folder to something else? Do a recursive search in the Apache ServerRoot to see if you have any configuration related to `symbols`: `grep -lr 'symbols' /etc/apache2`.

Comment: I got 404 errors when looking at the logs and there is no mention of 'symbols' in /etc/apache2. I solve the problem though.

Comment: FWIW, use of extinfo is deprecated as of Nagios v3. You can supply all of that info directly in host definitions. See http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#host

Comment: What user is apache running as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ubuntu, the `nagios3` package installs all the files that are served by the web interface into `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/`.

Additional images to be used for the maps can be installed via the `nagios-images` package and the files are installed in `/usr/share/nagios/htdocs/`.

You can note that one path is referring to `nagios3` while the other is referring to `nagios`.

In addition, `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos` contains a list of symbolic links that points to sub-directories in `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos`. However, the `symbols` symbolic link is actually missing and this is why the maps cannot use files from that directory.

Creating the symbolic link such as below solves the problem:

```
/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos# ls -l symbols
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Dec  3 04:31 symbols -> 
  ../../../../nagios/htdocs/images/logos/symbols/
```